# Next.js application with Prisma ORM and Neon Datasource

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am struggling hard to connect to a neon database from a vercel edge function using a prisma client. After searching through the docs, I found out that neon has a serverless driver. I tried to use it how it is specified in the docs:

```js
"use server";

import { Pool, neonConfig } from "@neondatabase/serverless";
import { PrismaNeon } from "@prisma/adapter-neon";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import ws from "ws";

export const createPost = async (userId: string, content: string) => {
  neonConfig.webSocketConstructor = ws;
  const connectionString = `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`;

  const pool = new Pool({ connectionString });
  const adapter = new PrismaNeon(pool);
  const prisma = new PrismaClient({ adapter });

  await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      userId: userId,
      content: content,
    },
  });

  await prisma.$disconnect();

  await pool.end();
};
```

However, I keep getting this error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Promise' at **webpack_require****. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Would love to know if there's a fix for this, struggling with the same error to run Prisma from the edge with the Neon serverless driver.